# Should I use Elastic Search as my data store instead of MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx, elasticsearch

I am about to rebuild my web application to use elastic search instead of mysql for searching purposes, but I am unsure exactly how to do so.

I watched a Laracon video on it, since my application is built on Laravel 4.2, and I will be using this wrapper to query: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch

However, am I still going to use the MySQL database to house the data, and have ES search it? Or is it better to have ES house and query the data.

If I go the first route, do I have to do CRUD operations on both sides to keep them updated?

Can ES handle the data load that MySQL can? Meaning hundreds of millions of rows?

I'm just very skiddish on starting the whole thing. I could use a little direction, it would be greatly appreciated. I have never worked with any search other than MySQL.

Comment: A good use case of ES is creating an indexed, searchable JSON front for a data store. That backend data store could be MySQL, or log files, or whatever. It can use distributed system but I think that's a bit overkill for the backend of a Laravel app.

Comment: The reason i'm asking is because the database has millions of rows, each day hundreds of thousands get added and deleted so the fulltext index gets slower and I fond myself optimizing the table daily, if I use elastic search I am under the assumption that it will no longer be necessary and I can let it run all its operations without me needing to deal with that every day.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend keeping MySQL as the system of record and do all CRUD operations from your application against MySQL. Then start an ElasticSearch machine and periodically move data from MySQL to ElasticSearch (only the data you need to search against).

Then if ElasticSearch goes down, you only lose the search feature - your primary data store is still ok.

ElasticSearch can be configured as a cluster and can scale very large, so it'll handle the number of rows.

To get data into Elastic, you can do a number of things:

1. Do an initial import (very slow, very big) and then just copy diffs with a process. You might consider something like Mule ESB to move data (http://www.mulesoft.org/).
2. When you write data from your app, you can write once to MySQL and also write the same data to Elastic. This provides real time data in Elastic, but of course if the second write to Elastic fails, then you'll be missing the data.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but how do you convert MySQL to JSON? Do you export it? Do you use a tool to convert it? Shall I dump it or a direct query from MySQL?